# "Одиноко солирующая песнь" - возможно ли, хотя бы иронически (песнь в значении рассказ)?

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

> Начнём с формальностей, прежде чем я заведу свою одиноко солирующую
> песнь (а заведу!).

Comment: Относительно **заведу**: «Эх, гуляй душа казацкая! Затянем песню, что ли!!» и «Лишь мы затянем песню, как все скворцы в округе...».

Comment: Ой-ё! Нальзя завести песнь, которая рассказ; ея можно только ЗАТЯНУТЬ? Ты меня пугаешь! Я вышла из положения иначе: проблемное сбросила в коммент: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4313506-marija-vasilevna-rozanova-kto-eto-chem-izvestna-kakaja-biografija.html#answer12381326

Comment: "Идет направо – ***песнь заводит***, / Налево – сказку говорит..."

Comment: _**«…одиноко солирующую песнь»**_ === Мне нравится!

Comment: Я ж, который пугает, не про нельзя,  а про можно (если по контексту подходяще).

Answer (score 1):

***Одиноко солирующая песнь?***

1. Думаю, что нет.

**СОЛИРОВАТЬ**, -рую, -руешь; св. и нсв. Исполнить — исполнять соло; быть солистом. С. в хоре. В оркестре солировали духовые инструменты. В первой части симфонии солировала флейта. Солирование, -я; ср.

**[Сочетаемость для "солирующий"](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9).** Солирующий голос, солирующая флейта, скрипка.  А песня — это не инструмент.

Песня как голос? ***Одиноко звучащая песнь?*** Но тогда: солирующая песнь.

2. Возможные варианты: **Одинокое соло. Мое одинокое соло**.
3. **Примеры:**

[Одиночество соло для скрипки](https://stihi.ru/2006/08/27-1719) (стихотворение).

["Одинокое соло трубы"](https://vk.com/wall-129036197_143) — название книги.

**P.S.**  С другой стороны, можно принять все эти **условности**, то есть посчитать рассказ-песню за голос, а в тавтологии увидеть художественный **повтор**. К тому  же в **названиях** больше свободы,  чем где-либо еще. И тогда сделаем вывод: ничего, нормально. По принципу: «Суха, мой друг, теория везде, Но **древо жизни пышно зеленеет»**.